# passing a filename as argument in matlab

Tags: matlab

In `matlab` I have a function which should take in a file name.
This file has a struct in it, later this file should be executed with in the function so that the struct will be loaded to the work space.

For example:

My function is `hello(a)`, where 'a' is a file name, this file has a struct.

On executing the file in command window this struct will be loaded in the workspace.
Same way I want the struct to be loaded in to the workspace when I call the function.

I tried `eval(a)`, but this is not loading the struct in the file to the workspace.

From the file name how will I obtain the struct name, even though I know that there is a struct in the file, but this is going to vary dynamically.

**So how should I return the structure in function?**

Comment: Why won't you declare the file to be called (matlab script) as a matlab [function](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/function.html)? The function would output the desired structure. I don't get the point of working with filenames.

Comment: i have a file named "network",this have a struct called 'Dom0.Dir1'....Struct name vary from file to file..i am passing the file name through a function called "hello('network')"...with in the function,i have to obtain the structs name,so that i can access the variables and values in the struct..only info i am sending is the file name as an argument in the function

Comment: Please provide more details regarding the format of file "network"

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether you want the struct (or structs) inside the file to be copied automatically to the workspace, or if you want to assign the data yourself.

The following solution copies all variables from file `a` to the "base"-workspace automatically using the `assignin()` function. The solution also assumes that you give it a file for a .mat file.

```
function hello(a)
   all_structs = load('-mat', a);
   var_names = fieldnames(all_structs);
   for k = 1:length(var_names)
      assignin('base', var_names{k}, all_structs.(var_names{k}));
   end
end
```

Comment: But this is basically the same as double-clicking a .mat file in the MATLAB current directory. perhaps this is not what you want then.

Comment: i have a file named "network",this have a struct called 'Dom0.Dir1'.Struct name vary from file to file..i am passing the file name through a function called  "hello('network')"...with in the function,i have to obtain the structs name,so that i can access the variables and values in the struct..only info i am sending is the file name as an argument in the functin

Comment: You can always use the "S = load('arg1', 'arg2', ...)" form of the load function. The struct S will contain all variables in the file. Some intelligent use of function fieldnames() is probably also necessary. Look at my function above, I use both methods there.

Comment: Error using ==> load
Number of columns on line 1 of ASCII file C:\Anoop\task_Jeff wong\GlobalCrossing.m
must be the same as previous lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try `eval`:

```
function mystruct = readstruct(filename)
% ... read in text from file here ...
eval(text)
```

For example, assume your file contains text `'mystruct.myval = 1'`, then after reading the file contents into string `text`, `eval(text)` returns

```
mystruct = 

    myval: 1
```

To load the structure into the workspace, the function should return the structure.

If the file contains arbitrary data (presumably but not necessarily in ascii format) then you can simply assign it to a structure after the file is read:

```
function mystruct = readstruct(filename)
% ... read in text from file here ...
% ... perform conversion of data type ...
mystruct.value = values
```

Comment: my file named text have a struct in it..but i dont know its name..how can i obtain the name of the struct in the file.

Comment: how will i come to know that my structure is mystruct

Comment: Can you provide more details? Does this file already exist? Can you show it (or the relevant part?) Is it a text (ascii) file or .mat? My example was generic: I merely show how you could read in a text file in which a structure assignment is made. I edited to show a different possible scenario.